# is it possible to create an array where we do not know the amount of elements at initialisation? (dealing with inheritance/polymorphism)

Tags: c++

Problem: I need an array (datamember) in a parent class A. 
However, depending on the child class, that array should have a different number of elements.

Is this possible?
If yes, how can I do this? (without dynamic allocation)
If no, then is there any way around? (without dynamic allocation)

Thanks

Comment: How about `std::vector`? (Make sure to `#include <vector>`)

Comment: A `std::vector` is just a nice wrapper around a dynamically allocated array. If he doesn't want dynamic allocation, then he doesn't want dynamic allocation.

Comment: Why do you need a plain but differently sized c-array in the base class? There might better solutions to that problem than trying to mutilate the inheritance concept into something it isn't?

Comment: Mostly just experimentation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you plan on using said parent class, but you can accomplish what you've described using templates.

```
template<size_t N>
class Parent
{
    int data[N];
}

class Child : public Parent<4>
{
}
```

This has many limitations (such as being unable to use a Parent class pointer really), but it avoids having the dynamic allocation.

EDIT --- Since you need true access to a parent array, here is an alternative.

```
class Parent
{
    const size_t mSize;

public:
    Parent(size_t size) : mSize(size) {}

    inline size_t Size() { return mSize; }
    virtual int* GetData() = 0;
}

template<size_t N>
class Child : public Parent
{
    int mData[N];

public:
    Child() : Parent(N) {}

    virtual int* GetData() { return mData; }
}

class Grandchild : public Child<8>
{
public:
    GrandChild() {}
}
```

Comment: hmm, maybe I could give an extra parameter in the constructor or something as to how many elements it should have. Because I actually need the parent class

Comment: 1) Now the derived classes aren't related anymore at all; 2) "parent" and "child" are not very good metaphors for inheritance in C++. A child neither "is-a" parent (unless you live in the north), nor is a child "implemented in terms of" a parent. Good metaphors for "base class" and "derived class" are "Base" and "Derived".

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw: You could make `Grandchild` derive *privately* from `Child<8>`, since this is the "is-implemented-in-terms-of" metaphor on the nose. You'll need to slingshot through a non-virtual public in the base and a private virtual: `int * getData() { return this->getDataImpl(); }`

Comment: However, it's not an array datamember anymore. I have no problems with pointers but it's just to be exact. It can't be done with an array datamember for the reasons mentioned by KerrekSB/Nicol Bolas

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. The size of every C++ type must be known at compile time.

This is exactly what dynamic allocation exists to do.

You can however, use the Curriously Recurring Template Pattern:

```
template<int NumValues>
class BaseClass
{
  private:
    int theArray[NumValues];
};

class Derived1 : public BaseClass<12>
{
  ...
};

class Derived2 : public BaseClass<154>
{
  ...
};
```

However, `BaseClass<12>` and `BaseClass<154>` are *not* the same type. So `Derived1` and `Derived2` are not polymorphic with each other. That's the limitation: each type must have a known size.

Comment: it should be possible to determine this at compile time though, just not at initialisation

Comment: Yes, the size must be known at compile time, but that doesn't stop him from accomplishing what he wants to do.

Comment: @xcrypt: If it's not known at initialization time, then it's not known at compile time. Since compiling happens *first*. Also, see my edit for a possible solution, depending on your particular needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for a static array. Remember that inheritance means that *every* derived class has the same base subclass.

So if `A::array` has `N` elements, and `B : A` and `C : A` are derived classes, then the `A`-subobject's array of both `B` and `C` must also have `N` elements.

Possible solutions:

1. Use a dynamic datastructure.
2. Don't use inheritance, at least not from a common baseclass. For instance, you can have `B : A<N>` and `C : A<M>`, where `B` and `C` are now totally unrelated classes and `A` is a *template* containing an array of the desired size. (Of course you can additionally inherit from a separate common baseclass or let `A<N>` do so.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just have the base class storing a ptr and size, but those can point into the derived class's data.

```
  class Base {
       int *data;
       size_t size;
  };

  class SimpleDerived : public Base {
       int mydata[42];
       SimpleDerived() {
           data = &mydata[0]; 
           size = 42; // or sizeof(mydata) / sizeof(mydata[0])     
       }
  };

  template <int N>
  class Derived : public Base {
       int array[N];
       Derived() {
          data = &array[0];    
          size = N;
       }
  }
```

If that indirection is unacceptable, you need to rethink how you plan to solve the problem (see my comment).

Note that this has the same memory overhead as adding any virtual function to Base (ptr to vtable) but it's faster when accessing the data, since you avoid a virtual function call. (Just a ptr dereference to data that's nearby and thus should be fetched to the cache simultaneously). The vtable may be anywhere and thus slower.

Comment: this doesn't even have to be a template though, since the derived class knows how much elements it contains. Apart from that, a splendid simple solution.

Comment: @xcrypt: true.. I'll add an example to match that.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a viable solution if you can't use templates or dynamic arrays:

```
struct base {
  int array_base[8];
  virtual int& get_array(size_t x) { return array_base[x]; }
};

struct derived1 : base {
  int extend_array[10]; // extend to 18
  virtual int& get_array(size_t x) { return (x < 8) ? array_base[x] : extend_array[x - 8]; }
};
```

Use `get_array()` instead of accessing the array directly.

I don't recommend this. Chances are you should rethink your design.